# Drupal commerce product catalog

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-commerce

I want To create a product cataloge page which has
Two section on one side there will be all products
And on the  other side there will be filters to select
The products which has the specific taxonomy term attached to it.

Is there any way i can achieve this.... I am using drupal 7 with drupal commerce

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has got nothing specific to do with Drupal commerce.

It can be easily done with the [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module.

1. You can create a a page display, set all the fields that you want to
   display.
2. Create one contextual filter that will filter based on the
   taxonomy term from the url.
3. Create all the filters that you wish to display to the user.
4. Make sure that you select the checkbox "expose
   to the user" to make it visible to the end user.

You are good to go. If you are particular about having the filters side by side to the catalog, select the option create a block with the exposed filter option. And then place the block [available on your block listing page] accordingly.